# Why android studio automatically reorders views and elements in graphical layout editor

Tags: android, android-layout

I was curious about knowing that why this happens in android studio when I'm trying to graphically edit layouts. Every views and attributes are reorganised. is there any rendering benefits or any benefits at all?

Answer (score 5):

Because its not a drag and drop editor.  Not really.  You're putting children into a parent layout, which works on certain rules.  When you drag children around, you change the rules but you're never putting it in a particular place.

I really, really, really suggest you don't use the graphical layout editor.  Its confusing, not very accurate (especially if using custom views) and inefficient.  Learn how to write layout xml, you'll be much faster and write easier to maintain layouts.  Most pro devs don't use it at all.